# How to change textView text then wait then change it again multiple times

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a fake loading screen type of program.
I want it to show 1% then wait 3 seconds then show 15% then wait 3 seconds then show 25% and so on.
I can set the text like this:

```java
prTextView.setText("1%");
```

How would I do that in java? I found multiple tutorials, but they only did it once not multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CountDownTimer`. Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer#java

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText(100 - (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "%");
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("100%");
     }
 }.start();
```

Comment: Starts from 970 and ends in 100. Doesn't work the way I intended it to.

Comment: Actually you can fix it like this:
```mTextField.setText(100 - (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "%");
```
and also setting the millisInFuture to 100000

Comment: Marking as answer since it did lead me to the right one

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion (a function calling itself) to loop some functionality. Use the Handler class to wait.

```
void updateProgress(){
        progress++;
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            if(progress < 100)
                updateProgress();
        },3000L);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this `Runnable thread` .

```
    private void fakeProgress() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            final String[] status = {"1%","15%", "25%", "35%", "49%", "60%", "79%", "100%"};
            int arraySize = status.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                Log.d("ZI", status[i]);
                String status_part = status[i];
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("........" + status_part);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```